# My {{ item.img.url }} doesnt work, doesnt even display url

Tags: python, django

So basicaly I am making an information panel and sometimes there needs to be a photo attached. I can assure you I searched the whole internet for the solution and yet after two hours I am here and need help. Please restore my sanity.

My index.html - I am posting only the part where theres the {{ item.img.url }}

```
<ul class="list-ohlasky">
  {% for item in ohlasky %}
  <li class="polozka-ohlasky"> {{ item.den }}<br>
  {{item.text}}</li>
    {% if item.img %}
      <img src="{{ item.img.url }}" alt="PLS WORK">
    {% else %}

    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Ohlasky
from .models import Liturgicketexty
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
import datetime


# Create your views here.

now = datetime.datetime.now()

def index(request):
    order = Ohlasky.objects.all().order_by('den').values()
    order1 = Liturgicketexty.objects.all().order_by('id').values()
    template = loader.get_template('blog/index.html')
    context = {
        'ohlasky': order,
        'liturgicketexty': order1,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Here is models.py

```
from django.db import models



# Create your models here.

class Ohlasky(models.Model):
    den = models.DateField(blank=False)
    nazev = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
    text = models.TextField(blank=False)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazev + ' | ' + str(self.den)
```

Here is urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('kontakt/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('bohosluzby/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('zivotfarnosti/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('pastorace/', include('blog.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Nad lastly settings.py

also I imported os

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I dont know anymore. I will appreciate every solution. Thank you.

Comment: Do you see the `img` tags in your html output with just the `src` attributes empty? Or are you missing the entire `img`elements?

Answer (score -1):

remove the values method from order object,
the return value from `values()` is a python dictionary and you can't access keys with dot notation

```py
def index(request):
    order = Ohlasky.objects.all().order_by('den')
    order1 = Liturgicketexty.objects.all().order_by('id')
    template = loader.get_template('blog/index.html')
    context = {
        'ohlasky': order,
        'liturgicketexty': order1,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: In the django template language, that's exactly what you can. That should not be the issue. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/language/#variables

Comment: Note tho, that the dot notation is not the reason, but that `values` serializes an image field to its `name` attribute.

Comment: `you can't access keys with dot notation` is misleading: image just did not _expand_ to 
a dictionary by `values` call. `values` in the original code was of no use and just led to this issue. @YusufAdel

Comment: It is not only misleading, but plain wrong. You **can** access keys with dot notation in a django template. `item.img` does resolve, otherwise the whole if part would not evaluate. The problem is that  values makes `item["img"]` resolve to a string (`item.img.name` in Python) which in turn has neither an attribute nor a key `url`.